# Android TabLayout Open different tab programaticly

Tags: android

Hi everyone I have some problem. My application have TabLayout and I have A Dialogs when new data is coming on web service a popup message will visible. When I push the popup message button , I want to open my list which is my other activity and its place third tabs. Sorry my English , I want to open other tabs programaticly(When I push button other tabs its open. ) and I do not find any example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in here http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html you can call

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
```

to switch the tab. If you want that to happen in a newly launched Activity you can pass the tab to open in the intent ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29 ) and do the switching in the `onCreate()`.